# Codeigniter welcome page not showing, shows garbled text instead

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation

As soon as I unzip CodeIgniter-3.1.9/ from the installer .zip file, I opened `localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/' and it shows a lot of garbled text instead of the welcome page.

```
=')) { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED); } else { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE); } break; default: header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.'; exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR } /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory. * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file. */ $system_path = 'system'; /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want this front controller to use a different "application" * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do, * use an absolute (full) server path. * For more info please see the user guide: * * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html * * NO TRAILING SLASH! */ $application_folder = 'application'; /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want to move the view directory out of the application * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default * to the standard location inside your application directory. * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path. * * NO TRAILING SLASH! */ $view_folder = ''; /* * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * DEFAULT CONTROLLER * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file. * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those * special instances where you might want to override the standard * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation. * * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need * to call functions dynamically via the URI. * * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature */ // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" directory. Leave blank // if your controller is not in a sub-directory within the "controllers" one // $routing['directory'] = ''; // The controller class file name. Example: mycontroller // $routing['controller'] = ''; // The controller function you wish to be called. // $routing['function'] = ''; /* * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file. * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different * config values. * * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature */ // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item'; // -------------------------------------------------------------------- // END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS. DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE // -------------------------------------------------------------------- /* * --------------------------------------------------------------- * Resolve the system path for increased reliability * --------------------------------------------------------------- */ // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests if (defined('STDIN')) { chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); } if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE) { $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } else { // Ensure there's a trailing slash $system_path = strtr( rtrim($system_path, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } // Is the system path correct? if ( ! is_dir($system_path)) { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME); exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } /* * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * Now that we know the path, set the main path constants * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */ // The name of THIS file define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)); // Path to the system directory define('BASEPATH', $system_path); // Path to the front controller (this file) directory define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // Name of the "system" directory define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH)); // The path to the "application" directory if (is_dir($application_folder)) { if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE) { $application_folder = $_temp; } else { $application_folder = strtr( rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } } elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr( trim($application_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } else { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // The path to the "views" directory if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $view_folder = APPPATH.'views'; } elseif (is_dir($view_folder)) { if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE) { $view_folder = $_temp; } else { $view_folder = strtr( rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } } elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr( trim($view_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } else { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); /* * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * And away we go... */ require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Any idea what' gone wrong?

Btw I have moved my `var/www/html` folder to `/home/{name}/www` could that be a reason I am getting this output?

Comment: don't open PHP code in `Notepad`/`gEdit`. this will solve your issue.

Comment: If you are seeing PHP code, then you haven't got PHP talking to your Apache or NginX

Comment: my bad, hadn't installed PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the content above shows, that means your PHP code in not execute my apache and php.

try run the apache and php services or may services not install correctly.

you can check it by that all things running fine o not.

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```